# Perdida de table en Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php7

¿Como estas? lo que pasa, ayer estaba trabajando en mi proyecto, en la noche deje de trabajar en el, cuando hoy en la tarde lo abrí me salen los siguientes errores, pero al revisar la base de datos en MySql veo que se elimino una tabla pero yo no la elimine se desapareció no se como ya no esta y no tengo un backup aparece lo siguiente, como puedo recuperar esta tabla y por que sucedió esto¿?

"Supongo que los errores salen por que falta la tabla"

**Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\departamento\dashboard.php on line 18**

[image: ERROR 1]

***CODIGO ERROR 1 ***

```
<div class="animated flipInY col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <div class="tile-stats">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i></div>
   <div class="count"><?php echo mysqli_num_rows($TicketData) ?></div>
    <h3>Actividades Pendientes</h3>
     </div>
      </div>
```

**Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\departamento\ajax\tickets.php on line 55**

[image: ERROR 2]

***CODIGO EEROR  2***

```
$adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
 $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
  //Count the total number of row in your table*/
   $count_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  
    $sWhere");
     $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
      $numrows = $row['numrows'];
       $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
```

**Error que sale al intentar abrir mi tabla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**No te que la tabla dice que esta en uso!**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Revisaste en PHPMyAdmin directamente para ver si las tablas no están ¿? Si se borraron no lo hicieron solas, alguien lo hizo, un virus, un menor que se puso a manipular el PC, tú que te quedaste dormido y se te fue un dedo hacia el botón delete, etc.

Comment: Revise PHPMyAdmin , la tabla esta pero al intentar acceder a ella sale el error,  #1932 - Table 'tareasti.ticket' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: ¿Cómo? ¿La tabla aparece en el panel de la izquierda y luego cuando intentas acceder te dice que no existe?

Comment: En algunos casos ha funciona lanzar estas dos instrucciones: `ALTER TABLE tareasti.ticket DISCARD TABLESPACE;`  seguida de `ALTER TABLE tareasti.ticket IMPORT TABLESPACE;` ¿Sólo pasa con esa tabla o con todas? Porque puede ser un problema de phpmyadmin mismo que necesite ser actualizado. Sería interesante que intentaras acceder por consola y verificar si se puede acceder a la tabla de esa manera.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, señor eso pasa

Comment: Si señor solo pasa con esa tabla

Comment: 1. ¿Probaste a ingresar por consola? 2. ¿Probaste a ejecutar los `ALTER TABLE` de más arriba?

Comment: Si señor los ejecute y sale esto: MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1932 - Table 'tareasti.ticket' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: Pero ¿entraste a mysql por la consola o estás en PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Entre por  PHPMyAdmin , señor @A.Cedano note algo voy adjuntar la imagen el la publicación de la pregunta puedes mirar la imagen me aparece que la tabla esta en uso

Comment: Intenta reparar la base de datos o la tabla, está entre los comandos de PHPMyAdmin. También aprende a usar mysql por consola, es más rápido y eficaz sobre todo para este tipo de cosas.

Comment: Intenta reparar desde la interfaz gráfica lanzando esta consulta: `REPAIR TABLE tareasti.ticket`. Si no te deja tendrás que tratar de entrar por consola para intentar recuperar la tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias señor @A.Cedano

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91733/discussion-between-esteban-giraldo-and-a-cedano).